# Is possible to bridge a LAN connection that requires EAP authentication to a separate wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I'm attempting to create my own private network in my school's dorm rooms in order to connect several devices that do no support WPA2-enterprise networks such as a Google Home and a Google Chromecast. The school provides ethernet ports in all dorm rooms that require EAP MSCHAPv2 authentication.

The setup I'm trying to accomplish is as follows:

1. The router is connected to the ethernet port and is authenticated using my school login
2. The router broadcasts a WiFi network that receives internet access from the wired connection

I have been able to accomplish a similar setup by connecting my laptop to the WPA2-enterprise school network, and connecting the same laptop via ethernet to a router. I then bridged the two networks from the Windows network adapter settings menu. However, this setup requires that I have my laptop on and in the room, which is very inconvenient. I would like to use the ethernet port that the school offers to achieve a similar setup.

I am new to the field of networking, so I apologize in advance for any misused terminology.

Comment: This is going to require some "brains" to perform the operation... Is a Rasberry Pi or Asus Tinkerboard a feasible option? It can perform the necessary authentication and routing functions needed, but most routers do not have that capability built in. That said, have you checked with your schools IT dept about this? It is likely against policy to perform such things, and most schools have the ability to white list things like streaming devices, game consoles, etc. rather than have you circumvent their network security.

Comment: If your wired Ethernet ports require EAP-MSCHAPv2 authentication, that means they use 802.1X, and they won't accept frames from MAC addresses that have not authenticated. This means you will need to run NAT on your device so that it makes it look like all the traffic is coming from that one device's MAC address instead of the wireless devices' real MAC addresses.

Comment: @acejavelin I have spoken with the IT department at the school, and they said school policies disallow the from allowing access to non 802.1X devices. That said, they said they had nothing against me using the bridging technique with my laptop. Yes, a raspberry pi is a feasible option if you could point me to the right direction.

Comment: @RashidAlAbri can I ask if you have ended up succeeding at setting up a private network. I am trying to achieve a similar thing, hoping to connect my smart home devices in a college dorm I have just entered.